# Passing data to another page

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I came up with a formula for a unique order id. The logic is to insert the unique id into the participants table as well as bring forth the unique order id to other pages, but i do not know the proper way of doing it. Is it through session as well, linking it to the variable like i tried on the last line of the code preview? Thanks

```
public function addBooking($data,$event_id) {
        $e_user_id = $this->session->data['e.user_id'];
        $date = date('Y-m-j H:i:s', time());

        $counter = sizeof($data['name']);

        $curdate =  date("d").date("m").date("y");
        $unique_id = uniqid();
        $special_id = $unique_id.$curdate;

        for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++){
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "e_participant SET 
                        e_participant.fname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name'][$i]) . "', 
                        e_participant.date_added = '" .$this->db->escape($date) . "', 
                        e_participant.order_id = '" . $special_id . "',
                        e_participant.user_id = '".(int)$e_user_id."'");
        }
        $e_special_id = $this->session->$special_id;


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is basically assigning the variable to a session. Allowing the session to store the variable will allow you to bring forth the session stored to other pages, if that would be what you aim for.

```
$this->session->data['your_id'] = $special_id;
```

The code above is an example where you can use and try to experiment more on this. As you can see above, the session is storing your special_id variable, hence you can now add this to any other pages to use the data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for